# Is apt-get -f install safe?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded VirtualBox for Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04 from the [Oracle website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), and then installed it using: `dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb` in the terminal. Now I need to install the missing dependencies.

How do I know the dependencies are safe? Where do they come from? Do they come from the Ubuntu official repositories, VirtualBox or some third party?

Results of `sudo apt-get -f`:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdouble-conversion3 libpcre2-16-0 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
  libsdl1.2debian libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 python-is-python2 python2
  python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qttranslations5-l10n
Suggested packages:
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5 python2-doc python-tk python2.7-doc
  binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libdouble-conversion3 libpcre2-16-0 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
  libsdl1.2debian libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 python-is-python2 python2
  python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qttranslations5-l10n
0 to upgrade, 24 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 14.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 62.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Edit: '`1 not fully installed or removed`' was virtualbox package itself. I have now removed virtualbox using `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox` and reinstalled using `apt install virtualbox` which has automatically installed dependencies needed. I know these are safe, and from Ubuntu Official repositories, as I don't have other unsupported third party repositories enabled (option for these is unchecked in software and update centre).

Comment: FYI, your REAL problem is the line `1 not fully installed or removed.` You must learn how to determine which package has the problem, and how to troubleshoot that problem. Try the Search box at the top of every AskUbuntu page -- it's a fairly common new-user question.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   Eoan refers to 19.10 or an EOL (*end-of-life*) release of Ubuntu and may be a security risk having gone some time without upgrades of security fixes.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: That version won't be in any supported repository; it'll only be fond in old-releases.ubuntu.com as 19.10/eoan is EOL and I wouldn't use it, but instead use the normal focal release available in Ubuntu repositories.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/virtualbox  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  FYI:  Each release has a codename, *eoan* was 19.10 (or 2019-October release), the next release 20.04 (2020-April) is *focal* (next letter in the alphabet; F).. followed by *groovy* 20.10 (2020-October)....  the *eoan* is seen in the filename showing intended releases..

Comment: @guiverc The virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb in the question is listed as a package for Ubuntu 19.10 / 20.04 on the official Oracle VirtualBox website. I edited the question to add a link to the website where this package can be found. I hope this edit will prevent any confusion that this question could be EOL because the name of the .deb file in the question contains *eoan*. The author of the question has already commented that he is using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: A fundamental question to the OP would be: Do you ***really*** need to use the version provided on the Oracle web site? For normal users, `apt install virtualbox` would be all that is needed. More detailed instructions can be found at: https://linuxconfig.org/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: @karel Just clarifying, it is not a security risk, even though the file contains 'eoan' (Because is listed as 'for 20.04' also on Oracle website)? I did not install any dependencies, I never used Virtualbox, and have now removed/purged it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All dependencies installed by `apt-get -f install` can only be installed from your software sources, so if any of your software sources are unsafe then `sudo apt-get -f install` is unsafe too. In the case of a vanilla Ubuntu installation where only the default Ubuntu repositories are enabled, then `sudo apt-get -f install` would be safe, but since packages from the default Ubuntu repositories don't conflict with each other a suggestion in the terminal to run this command ordinarily wouldn't appear in the terminal.

To let `apt` automatically configure dependencies, open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the directory the contains virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb, and run the following command

```
sudo apt install ./virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
```

instead of using `dpkg -i`. Then you won't have to run `sudo apt -f install` afterwards. A command of the form `sudo apt install ./package-name.deb` automatically installs all the dependency packages that are required to install the .deb package. It also installs the recommended packages by default, but apt has an option to disable installing recommended packages for an individual command. It should also be noted that the current working directory in the terminal should be the same directory that contains package-name.deb, so that apt can find package-name.deb in the current working directory.